# delay output of each line to a file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i am bailing a windows 8 phone app.
i have a method that searches for a specific text from a text box and outputs it to a list box if found. I am trying to delay the output of each line written to a list box so i ideally it would be first line,wait 5 seconds, second line, wait 5 seconds,etc. currently it only delays at first then outputs all the lines it finds at once.

suspect.text is what i am searching for
results is the listbox it is sent to.

```
public void ReadFile()
 {
   var str = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("MACAddresses.txt", UriKind.Relative));
   List<string> lines = new List<string>();
   using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(str.Stream))
   {
      string line;
      while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        if(line.Contains(Suspect.Text))
         {
           lines.add(line);
         }
       }
   {
   foreach (string output in lines)
   {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     results.items.add(output);
   {
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're blocking the UI thread, so it cannot update the ListBox. Solving this issue is good job for async programming:

```
public async Task ReadFile()
 {
   var str = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("MACAddresses.txt", UriKind.Relative));
   List<string> lines = new List<string>();
   using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(str.Stream))
   {
      string line;
      while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        if(line.Contains(Suspect.Text))
         {
           lines.add(line);
         }
       }
   }

   foreach (string output in lines)
   {
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     results.items.add(output);
   }
 }
```

Please note the `async` keyword that has been added in front of the method signature, and the return type that has been changed to `Task`. You'll have to use the `await` keyboard to properly call the `ReadFile` method:

```
await ReadFile(); // Don't forget to use the await keyword!
```

The method calling `ReadFile` will have to be marked as `async` as well, or the code won't compile.

Comment: i tried to add this to calling method but it bounces me back to the home screen instead of displaying the content.
     private async Task ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        await ReadFile();
      }

Comment: looked into it more and you where right. thanks a lot!!